# TFS 2017 on Prem Agent Service work folder number increments

Tags: tfs

My TFS 2017 agent service seems to want to create new work folders randomly: c:\agent_work\1,c:\agent_work\2,c:\agent_work\3,c:\agent_work\4 All the way up to 14 now.  What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each new build definition gets its own work folder - which is quite sensible actually :-)

Comment: That's a very different structure from TFS 2012.  I was using TFS 2012 before and we upgraded to TFS 2017 (finally).  Yes it does make sense.  TFS 2012 used the build definition name.  It looks like they are just using the ID now instead.  Is there a way to clear all these away safely?  I can't imagine deleting them outright is the right way to go.

Comment: You can use the REST API or the TFS database (or maybe just by looking into the folder) to figure out the relationship between build definition names and IDs. Then you can delete the IDs that are not in use anymore.